# How to enable DDL generation in Playframework 2.0

Tags: playframework, ddl, playframework-2.0

How i could generate database scheme based on model in play 2.0?
Is there any config for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's enabled by default, every time you modify any model Ebean plugin updates file /conf/evolutions/default/1.sql, so when you'll refresh app in browser it will ask you if you want to apply evolotions

BUT BEWARE! Ebean script will DROP any existing table and will create it from scratch after each model's modification. So it could be destructive in future ... If you'll finish basic modeling of app it's definitely better idea to disable Ebean DDL generation and start using [common Play's evolutions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Evolutions/)

Comment: It doesn't work. I was trying enable and disable evolutions. DB is not created.

Comment: Have you configured any DB storage in application.conf at all ? (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaDatabase + http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaEbean)

Comment: Yes, I have defined db.default.driver, db.default.url, db.default.user, db.default.password. And play was able to connect to db. But I didn't integrated it with JPA. I don't know, should i do this or not.

Comment: It start working after i have dropped 'play_evolutions' table. Strange behavior.

Comment: Yes it's little bit ... unfinished IMHO, it works ONLY if there is ONLY 1.sql file (no 2.sql, 3.sql etc.) and if this 1.sql is controlled with Ebean plugin (first 2 lines with proper comments)

Comment: For me that does not work, I mean I cannot get ebean to write ddl to 1.sql.  What are the two proper comments to put in 1.sql ?